# when i open jquery dialog twice, no tabs are working

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

Below is the function am calling on click of the button.
 Note: dialog box should open as many times user clicks on a button,   independent of others.

issue : when i open jquery dialog twice, no tabs are working . am loading the content from spring mvc model and view. it works fine for the first popup >and not happening for 2nd popup(modal:false)-->

```
function addU(){        
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs(   { ajaxOptions: { cache: false }});


        $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("dialog")
        .attr("id", ii++)
        .appendTo("body")
        .dialog({
          title: "test",
          create: function (event, ui) {},
          close: function () { $(this).remove() },
          open: function (event, ui) {},
          modal: false,
          position: ['center', 130],
          minWidth: 510,
          resizable: true,
          zIndex: 20000
        })
        .load("addUserPage",function() {
            alert( "Load was performed." );
        });


        }

Java :
    @RequestMapping(value="/addUserPage",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addUserPage(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        Login login1=new Login();
        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();

        modelAndView.addObject("login",login1);
        modelAndView.addObject("msg","hey  hiii");
        modelAndView.setViewName("addNewUser");
        return modelAndView;
    }

<!--jsp:-->

<div id="tabs" style="width:130%">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Main</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Roles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Additional</a></li>
        </ul>
        <script>
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        </script>
    </div>
```